# Why is there a doublet instead of a singlet in this Wittig reaction salt configuration NMR?

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectroscopy, nmr-spectroscopy

I did an NMR sample to my salt p-carboxybenzyl triphenylphosphonium bromide. I got a doublet at 5.26, and according to every article it belongs to the $CH_2$ next to $P^+$, but how come I didn't get a singlet for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Phosphorous exists entirely as $\ce{^31P}$, and $\ce{^31P}$ has a magnetic moment of 1/2 (just like a proton). Therefore, a single phosphorous will split any protons coupled to it into a doublet - as you observed. If you looked at the corresponding $\ce{^31P}$ NMR spectrum you would see that the phosphorous signal would be split into a triplet by the two protons.

Comment: and another question if i may, i got a very large peak at 3.38 in dmso, could it be water?

Comment: The water impurity signal can move around a bit depending on the water concentration, but I'd bet your signal is due to water. [This reference](http://www.chem.ucla.edu/~webspectra/NotesOnSolvents.html) says the water impurity in dmso absorbs at 3.3.  If the above answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: im having trouble finiding out another two multiplets in 7.08 and another in 7.56 at the same reaction ,my solvent was tolouene..

Comment: For peak identification it would probably be best if you opened a new question and included a copy of the nmr spectrum along with your experimental procedure.